# Adjust.io iOS SDK IDFA usage

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

I have integrated Adjust SDK (https://github.com/adjust/ios_sdk) for some analytics. I need to update application on App Store. Adjust uses AdSupport.framework and iAd.framework which are associated with IDFA. The problem is I do not know what to check because I do not show any ads in the application. These are the questions: [image: IDFA questions]

I have checked in Adjust documentation and I've found this: https://github.com/pitchtarget/adjust-ios-sdk/blob/master/doc/idfa.md. It says:

> If your app got rejected by Apple because your app is using the advertising identifier, this document is for you.
>   Contact us at support@adjust.io. We would like to make sure that you are aware of the consequences of removing IDFA support.

Does anybody knows the right way to answer these questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you are using idfa as per sdk github sample code.
Please set NO and submit.
I have used Google analytics and I was set IDFA YES and my app got rejected after that   I set NO and submitted app got live now.

Answer (score 4):

Adjust SDK integration guide advises that you should use `AdSupport.framework` inside of your app which is needed to access IDFA. Of course, you have an option not to do this, but I guess that depends on your intended usage of the Adjust platform. In case you have added this framework to your app and if Adjust SDK is allowed to read IDFA from within your app, you should select `YES` and select:

- `Attribute this app installation to a previously served advertisement`.
- `Attribute an action taken within this app to a previously served advertisement`.

`Serve advertisements within the app` is not needed **unless you are serving advertisement inside of your app**, but Adjust SDK itself does not need this box to be checked.